# How to solve "X has 1 features, but LinearRegression is expecting 3 features as input."?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, linear-regression

```
from sklearn import linear_model
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error
from math import sqrt
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from sklearn.preprocessing import PolynomialFeatures
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

def f(x):
 return np.sin(2*np.pi*x) + np.random.normal(scale=0.1, size=len(x))

NUM_SAMPLES=15
x = np.random.uniform(0,1,NUM_SAMPLES)
y = f(x)
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x, y, test_size=0.33)
plt.plot(x,y,'bo')
plt.show()
poly = PolynomialFeatures(degree=2)
X_train= poly.fit_transform(np.array(X_train).reshape(-1, 1))

regr = linear_model.LinearRegression()
regr.fit(X_train, y_train)
y_pred = regr.predict(np.array(X_test).reshape(-1, 1))

# The coefficients
print('Coefficients: \n', regr.coef_)
rmse=sqrt(mean_squared_error(y_test, y_pred))
# Root mean squared error
print('Root mean squared error: %.2f' % rmse)
```

Tried to reshape the X_train data and the X_test but gave me error

```
X has 1 features, but LinearRegression is expecting 3 features as input.
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the main problem was that you weren't applying the polynomial transform to `X_test` before running it through linear regression (the regression was fit on the *transformed* `X_train`). See the code snippet below for a working copy:

[image: result]

```py
from sklearn import linear_model
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error
from math import sqrt
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from sklearn.preprocessing import PolynomialFeatures
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
def f(x):
 return np.sin(2*np.pi*x) + np.random.normal(scale=0.1, size=len(x))

NUM_SAMPLES=15
x = np.random.uniform(0,1,(NUM_SAMPLES, 1))  #Make it a column vector
y = f(x)
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x, y, test_size=0.33)

plt.plot(x,y,'bo')
plt.show()
poly = PolynomialFeatures(degree=2)
X_train_transformed = poly.fit_transform(X_train)

#Now that you've fit it on X_train, use it to transform X_test:
X_test_transformed = poly.transform(X_test)

regr = linear_model.LinearRegression()
regr.fit(X_train_transformed, y_train)
y_pred = regr.predict(X_test_transformed)

# The coefficients
print('Coefficients: \n', regr.coef_)
rmse=sqrt(mean_squared_error(y_test, y_pred))
# Root mean squared error
print('Root mean squared error: %.2f' % rmse)
```